# How to display heatmap by using python ezhc(Highchart)

Tags: python-2.7, highcharts, data-visualization

I am trying to draw heat map for the following data using ezhc[EZHC module link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ezhc/0.4.8)

**I want display col3 values in the heat against the time stamp ie col1  (x-axis)**, however for some reason heatmap does not shows anything on the page.

```
    ,col1,           col2,  col3
2015-02-06 10:00:00,,45.619,46.4
2015-02-06 10:15:00,,41.731,46.4
2015-02-06 10:30:00,,42.739,46.4
2015-02-06 10:45:00,,42.509,46.4
2015-02-06 10:53:00,13.6,41.981,46.4
2015-02-06 10:58:00,12.7,41.453,47.3
2015-02-06 11:00:00,,40.925,47.3
2015-02-06 11:15:00,,40.262,47.3
2015-02-06 11:30:00,,42.653,47.3
2015-02-09 10:00:00,,58.205,55.4
2015-02-09 10:15:00,,56.88,55.4
2015-02-09 10:30:00,,57.37,72.0
2015-02-09 10:45:00,,57.11,72.0
2015-02-09 10:58:00,12.0,57.355,72.0
2015-02-09 11:00:00,,57.6,72.0
2015-02-09 11:15:00,,58.118,72.0
2015-02-09 11:30:00,,57.6,72.0
2015-02-09 11:45:00,,57.053,72.0
2015-02-09 11:58:00,15.6,57.9455,75.6
2015-02-09 12:00:00,,58.838,75.6
```

**Below is my python code**

```
g = hc.Highcharts()
idx,col,data =hc.build.series_heatmap(df)

g.xAxis.categories = idx[2]
g.yAxis.categories = col[2]
g.chart.type = "heatmap"
g.chart.height = 550

g.legend.layout = 'vertical'
g.legend.align = 'left'
g.legend.verticalAlign = 'top'
g.legend.x = 100
g.legend.y = 70
g.legend.floating = True
g.legend.borderWidth = 1

g.tooltip.enabled = True
g.tooltip.valueDecimals = 2
g.tooltip.headerFormat = '<b>{series.name}</b><br>'
g.tooltip.pointFormat = '{point.x} Celsius, {point.y} kWh'
g.exporting.enabled = False

g.chart.zoomType = 'xy'

g.credits.enabled = True
g.credits.text = ''
g.credits.href = ''

tempPlot=g.plot(save=True, save_name='heatmap')
```

Comment: A highcharts heatmap typically is going to have an `x`, `y`, and `value`. Here you are only supplying the `x` as COL 1 and the `value` as COL 3. What is your `y`?

Comment: Actually COL3 is the value and COL3 max and min value becomes Y-axis values

Comment: Are you sure you want to render heatmap? Your data looks like more suitable for line/column type series. Anywya, I think the problem is that you set: `idx[2]` while should be `idx`. The same for `col`.